# Add point when user clicks on Charts - 'LineChartView' (iOS-Charts)

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

There's a way to implement a method where, when user clicks on chart, I can know the x-y values to insert in my array?

I'm trying to use:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {}
```

but this method shows me the nearest point that I already have.

If I use:

```
@IBOutlet var chart: LineChartView! 

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longTouch(_:)))
self.chartView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func touch(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.chart)
}
```

the 'touchPoint' return the absolute view's x-y and not related to the chart.

Someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Which value you are suing from `chartValueSelected` method ? r u using `entry.x` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 'entry.x' and 'entry.y' and both take the nearest point previously inserted and not the point where I've touched. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this method only return nearest point of X & Y may I know why you need absolute touchpoint ?

Comment: I would like the user enter a new value through the touch. Now I've resolved with `let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: myChartView)`  `let touched: CGPoint = myChartView.valueForTouchPoint(point: touchPoint, axis: .right)`. Thanks for response!

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved adding a gesture recognizer to the view:

```
// Gesture Recognizer to add a new value
func addGesture() {
    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)))
    gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.3
    _chartView?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
```

in the gesture method I've used the  `valueForTouchPoint(point: _)` that inerith to the `LineChartView`.

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

        // Recognize the location in the view
        let touchLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self._chartView)
        // The 'x-y' value where user touch the view
        let touchedPoint: CGPoint? = self._chartView?.valueForTouchPoint(point: touchLocation, axis: .right)

        guard let point = touchedPoint else { return false }

        // save the value...

    return true
}
```

And, if I zoom or pan the chart, the method return the correct value x-y values.

Hope this will help someone!